# Get GridView horizontal spacing on Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

Is there any way to determine the horizontal spacing used by a `GridView` on Android 4.0.3 (API level 15)?

I have some working code targeting 4.1.x that uses `GridView.GetRequestedHorizontalSpacing()`, but this doesn't exist prior to API 16. Is there an equivalent to this, or a way to calculate it, on API level 15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get it using Reflection API.

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    try {
        Field field = gridView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mHorizontalSpacing");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        int hSpacing = field.getInt(gridView);

        field = gridView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mRequestedHorizontalSpacing");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        int reqHSpacing = field.getInt(gridView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```